# jQuery: $.append and $.html are not working

Tags: jquery

This should straightforward but I have no idea what is wrong.
I am making an ajax call when there is `onblur` event on a text field. Ajax request goes to backend and gets the response. Then I have to append that response next to the text field. But it's not working.
**HTML**

```
<input type="text" required="" id="123456" onblur="validateWithDB(this)"></input>
```

**Javascript**

```
function validateWithDB(field)
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"validate",
                    data: "fieldValue="+field.value,
                    success: function(response) {
                        alert(response);// this is correct
                        alert($(field).val());// this is correct
                        var result = '<span class="help-inline">'+response+'</span>'
                        alert(result) // this is correct
                        $(field).html(result);// Does not show up.
                    },
                    error:function (xhRequest, ErrorText, thrownError) {
                        alert('Error: '  + '  ' + xhRequest);
                    }
                });
            }
```

I tried both `$(field).html(result);` and `$(field).append(result);` but no luck.

Comment: You can't put a span into an input...

Comment: What is the value of 'field'?

Comment: But he can put text into an input :D

Comment: I want to put this span next to input field.

Comment: @JeevanJose field is the input, see his html

Comment: there is no </input> closing tag. Input self closes. and use val();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the span NEXT to the input, use `.after()`

```
$(field).after(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$(field).val(result);
```

If you want to append span after input use this:

```
$(field).after(result)
```

Comment: That'll obliterate the user entered value with HTML, not show the error message alongside it

Comment: @Rup +1 for "obliterate". HTML is so much more fun with war-metaphors.

Answer (score 2):

As tymeJV asid in the comment, you can't put HTML inside the input tag.

You can either set it as the value using `$(field).val(result)` but this doesn't make much sense.

Or you can insert it after using [`.after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/):

```
$(field).after(result);
```

This will display the HTML in result directly after the input.

Comment: `.insertAfter` will insert `field` after `result`.

Comment: Input field disappeared when I used `insertAfter`.